# Using the Battery Manager in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigator

im trying to hook the battery manager object to a angular controller however the controller object doesnt seem to be updating when the promise by `navigator.getBattery()` complete. here is what i came up with

```
(function(){
var app=angular.module('appBattery',[]);
app.controller('batteryController',['$window',function($window){
this.bat={};
this.level=this.bat.level;
$window.navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){
    setBattery(battery);
});
function setBattery(battery){
    this.bat=battery;
    console.log(this.bat);
}
console.log(this.bat);
}]);
})();
```

with this html

```
<div ng-app='appBattery'>
<div id="battery-status-bar" ng-controller='batteryController as battery'>
    <div class="battery">
        <div class="power">
        {{battery}}
            <div class="level"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="percentage">{{battery.bat.level}}</div>
    <div class="time">{{battery.bat.chargeTime +':'+battery.bat.dischargeTime}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

it can also be found on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fnnruzjw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your controller as syntax. Check out my updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/fnnruzjw/1/. There were a couple of issues at hand:

You needed to use $scope.$apply.

```js
$window.navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery){
 $scope.$apply(function() {
    setBattery(battery);
  });
});
```

Your this was referring to the wrong this (I changed it to be vm as is a popular convention).

You were losing the reference to your battery object when you were reassigning it. I used angular.copy to keep the reference.

```js
function setBattery(battery){
  angular.copy(battery, vm.bat);
 console.log(vm.bat);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `battery` to `$scope.bat` (inject $scope in your controller also). And you will probably need to do `$scope.$apply()` too. Pretty much replace `this` with `$scope`.

Comment: where would i put the $scope.$appy()? and why would it not work as a controller property?

Comment: for organization i prefer to use it as controller properties rather then scope the variables

Comment: You only have access to properties in `$scope` in your view. You need to use `$scope.$apply()` since `bat` is set in an async function not part of angulars normal digest cycle.

Comment: is there a way to add it to the $scope.$watch without assigning it to a scoped variable?

Comment: the battery manager is updating constantly but the scope doesnt seem to be watching it even after i do the $scope.$apply()

Comment: Please show your updated code in an update of the question. Or ask a new question.